# LIKE query with special characters causes "Invalid pattern string" exception

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access

winform Application get crash when I search for special character using Like Query.

```
strSQL = @"SELECT Patient_ID_Internal ,Patient_ID ,Patient_Title, Patient_Name,
                  Patient_MiddleName_Name, Patient_BirthDate,
                  Patient_RegDate,Patient_UIDNumber 
           FROM Patient_Master 
           WHERE Patient_ID LIKE +@paramPatient_ID +'%'
               AND Patient_Name LIKE +'%'+ @paramPatient_Name +'%'";

objOleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand(strSQL,
    Common.OleDbCommObject.OleDbConnectionObject);
objOleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramPatient_ID", txtPatientId.Text);
objOleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramPatient_Name", txtPatientName.Text);
```

In like parameter when I Pass the special character such as([],!,@ etc) it crashes gives me an error **Invalid pattern string** and also pass % as a parameter it gives me an whole records from DB.

Comment: the percentage (`%`) symbol in `SQL` means anything so by placing `LIKE '%%%'` is just saying find me something like anything

Comment: I hope all the string concat mistakes in this post are not in the real code?

Comment: `MS-Access` uses `*` and `?` instead of `%` and `_` respectively I think when you are using `%` these mean something else in `MS-Access` [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx) and [link](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-tips-for-using-wildcard-characters-in-microsoft-access-criteria-expressions/)

Comment: @SecretSquirrel Yes I know but why application get crash when I search for [[ ]]] such charecter

Comment: @IMMORTAL I would get your application to output the query you are executing, then I think you will find your mistake. Count your brackets, you are missing a opening `[`

Comment: @SecretSquirrel  I am not using any bracket inside the query or any where in my code

Comment: @SecretSquirrel The `*` and `?` wildcard characters are only used in queries that are run from within the Microsoft Access application itself. External applications (like this one) querying an ACE/Jet (Access) database need to use the `%` and `_` wildcard characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square brackets have special meaning in an Access SQL `LIKE` expression (ref: [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/like-operator-HP001032253.aspx)) so single `[` characters must be escaped as `[[]`. For example, the following code snippet will fail with "Invalid pattern string"...

```csharp
cmd.CommandText =
    "SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE LastName LIKE ?";
string s = "%abc[def%";  // test data
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", s);
OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

whereas this will work

```csharp
cmd.CommandText =
    "SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE LastName LIKE ?";
string s = "%abc[def%";  // test data
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", s.Replace("[", "[[]"));
OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```